# How can I determine the valid SNIs accepted by an SSL/TLS certificate?

Tags: ssl, sni

Something driving me nuts on this.. I am testing to an SSL certificate and using different SNIs to determine what is acceptable. I do not own/manage the cert, so am relying on s_client to give me the info. I know that there are several SNIs that will work. I also test with one that does not work, because I see the "Hostname mismatch" being returned.

I can use the -verify_hostname flag to see what works and what does not, with this command:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect {IP_ADDR}:443 -servername {SERVER_NAME} -verify_hostname {HOSTNAME - same as the servername} | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep 'Subject Alternative Name' -A2
```

There is only one SAN in the cert. And there is a CN that is not a wildcard. In other words, I see jack.whatever.com in the X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: output, and I see the same in the CN = jack.whatever.com

However, there are some other hostnames that are acceptable when sent in the -servername flag field. If don't use the -verify_hostname value, and I send an SNI that is not acceptable, I don't get a Hostname mismatch error and I get the default jack.whatever.com returned in the X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: field.
IF I SEND AN ACCEPTABLE SNI value, I get that (plus others!) returned in the X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: field.

To summarize, there are multiple acceptable SNIs, but there is only the one CN and SAN value. How can I determine all of the acceptable SNI hostnames? There is no info I can see other than just trying with some SNIs that I know work. I want to know about the unknown SNIs that work.  Please note that removing the grep part of the above command to get all of the info still does not show "acceptable" SNIs - the full output does not include this info.

Comment: I would just check the certificate, you can see all alternate address inside it. Only exception is a wildcard certificate, but it would be a *. There is no hidden address inside the certificate.

Comment: You can't check what certificates a server has available. A server can have a unlimited amount of certs. To me, this sounds like an X-Y problem. What *problem* are you trying to solve? Why do you want to find out what hosts the server offer?

Comment: The details of the certificate only show the CN. The output of the curl shows the SAN. I do not see a way to get this info other than hit or miss with the hostname in the curl or the verify hostname flags.

Comment: The problem I’m trying to solve is to get a full understanding of how SNIs and SANs and the CN interact in an SSL/TLS negotiation. I am a customer support person in cloud networking and get many questions specific to this issue. So, I guess if you solve MY problem, I will be paying it forward in spades.

Comment: Then ask [how SNI works](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/ssl/what-is-sni/)?

Comment: Thanks, but I’ve read that article and know how it works. Let me restate the question in a hopefully better way:  some SNIs work, some don’t. If the SNI value matches the CN or matches one of.the SANs, it is accepted. That is obvious. However, there are some that are accepted that match neither. And some that are not accepted. So there must be some values set somewhere, whether in the encrypted part of the cert or not, that govern this. The new question is where this set?

Comment: Maybe it’s at the ssl server itself past the cert challenge?  That would explain a lot. I think Steffan’s answer is the closest so far. I’ll investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A certificate does not accept an SNI. Instead a server will accept an SNI and then will continue the TLS handshake with the configured certificate.

This means that the server might not accept a domain as SNI even if the domain would match the certificate. But also that the server might accept a domain as SNI but serve a certificate which does not match the domain, in which case the client will hopefully complain about validation errors.

There is no way to query which domains are accepted as SNI by the server, one can only try.